# coldfusion 9 orm one-to-one multiple cfc

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using CF9 ORM -

I have an object model where I have multiple objects that could have a one-to-one relationship to a one particular object.  Is there a way to specificy the inverse relationship to one of two potential CFCs?

CFC 1a (ProblemType1):

```
property name="Product" cfc="Product" fieldtype="one-to-one" fkcolumn="productID" ;
```

CFC 1b (ProblemType2):

```
property name="Product" cfc="Product" fieldtype="one-to-one" fkcolumn="productID" ;
```

CFC 2:

```
property name="Problem" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc=???;
```

Can I use an interface for this? Or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CFC 1a and CFC 1b can both be subclasses of a parent entity, CFC 1. CFC 1 should have the relationship to "Product," which will be inherited by both of the subclasses. CFC 2 can then point to CFC 1 in its relationship.

Sample entities:

```
/** CFC 1 **/
component persistent="true" {

    property name="Product" cfc="Product" fieldtype="one-to-one" fkcolumn="productID";

}

/** CFC 1a **/
component persistent="true" extends="baseProblem" {

    // problemtype1 specific properties go here

}

/** CFC 1b **/
component persistent="true" extends="baseProblem" {

    // problemtype2 specific properties go here

}

/** CFC 2 **/
component persistent="true" {

    property name="Problem" fieldtype="one-to-one" cfc="baseProblem";

}
```

If you do take this approach, you'll probably need to look into [inheritance mapping](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS027D3772-2E98-4d5b-8800-054A62EBF8D9.html#WSE5000AA0-1A02-45c7-A251-3C41FF679326), specifically the `discriminatorColumn` and `discriminatorValue` attributes. Without knowing how your DB schema is set up, it's difficult to give further advice on this point, but the documentation should get you started.

Comment: My understanding of inheritance in relation to ORM was lacking. Thanks for the link and guidance.